# Customize Django ContentType

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-contenttypes

I have a model like this:

```
class BlockedItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=244)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

- In django admin, `content_type` fetch all models. Could I give only wanted models in `content_type` ?
- In `object_id`, is there any way to select from a list instead of enter `object_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only some models in content_type you can use

```
limit_choices = models.Q(app_label = 'myapp', model = 'MyModel') | models.Q(app_label = 'myotherapp', model = 'MyModelOtherModel') )
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to = limit_choices )
```

Comment: Many thanks, but what about "object_id"? I think I have to use a javascript that collect items for selected object. Am I right?

Comment: I think a solution can be **(not sure it is the better)** to override the admin form of your object [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) in order to have a prepopulated ChoiceFields with wanted value. And you will need some javascript to switch from one ChoiceField to an other when you change the content_type

Comment: Just check that models starts with small letters, like **mymodel**  not  **Mymodel**